# Print page content overwriting on header

Tags: jquery, css

page content over writing the header on the second page, please check the below code

```
 @media screen {
     div.divHeader
            {
                display: none;
            }
    }
    @media print {
      div.divHeader
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
            }
             div.divContent
            {
                 position: fixed;
                 top: 120px;
            }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer, heading placed in `<thead>`

```
<table>
     <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="10"><h1>My Header</h1></th></tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's because it is fixed. Therefore, it is shown in every page. Instead, change it to the absolute position.

Comment: I changed div.divContent position to absolute,but still it overwrites

Comment: Do it for both.

Comment: Then the header displays only on the first page

Comment: You wanna have the header in all pages but have a clear room between the content?

Comment: its a single report